# Spring date object in ExtJs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, extjs

I found many forum posts about the problem I want to ask, but I still can't figure out, so I hope that you will help me.

```
private Date ikeitimoData;
```

I have date object ikeitimoData and I save it to database as date object.
In spring this variable looks:

```
System.out.println(ikeitimoData);
// (answer) Fri Jun 13 2014 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

However, when I send request to get this value with ExtJs it looks:

```
1310428800000
```

it means it is converted to milliseconds, but it is still not a problem.

```
Ext.define('Turtas.model.Orlaiviai', {
extend: 'Turtas.model.BaseModel',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'ikeitimoData', type: 'date',
        convert: function (newValue, model) {
            console.log(new Date(newValue));
            return new Date(newValue);
        }
    },
]
```

});

I use this model to store data in grid. 
This is my grid column where i want to represent date.

```
columns:[  
     {  
        text: 'Įkeitimo data',
        dataIndex: 'ikeitimoData',
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        format:'Y-m-d'
        editor: {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            format: 'd-m-Y'
        }]
```

My displayed date looks like this:

```
Fri Jun 13 2014 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

Exact as it was in spring. I specified column xtype: 'datecolumn', I specified it's   format: 'Y-m-d'(so I want i to look like: 2014-06-13). But it doesn't change anything. If  I don't specify these properties everything looks the same. I tried many things, and have no idea how to solve this problem by myself, so I'm looking forward for your answers, thanks!

**UPDATE**

The problem was in my model. I switched field type to 'time' and everything works fine, because my answer from back-end was in milliseconds. Now everything works fine. I hope this problem solution will help someone too!

```
Ext.define('Turtas.model.Orlaiviai', {
extend: 'Turtas.model.BaseModel',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'ikeitimoData', type: 'time',
    },
]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Check if the package you are importing is `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date`. It should be `java.sql.Date`.